# Escaping semi-colon syntax in Perl

Tags: perl

How can I escape a semi-colon (that's syntax ) in perl by only adding characters after it?

Say I have a line of code:

```
print "foo";
```

I want to add the following code after it so it can repeat 5 times:

```
print "foo"; x 5;
```

Is there anyway I can escape/ignore the semicolon (without altering the original piece of code) so it can be interpreted as:

```
print "foo" x 5;
```

---

Edit: This seems like too much of a hassle, better off to just nest the line in a for loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just out of curiosity: why can't you remove the semicolon manually?

Comment: I'm confused. You appear to be asking how to modify the code, but you state you don't want to modify the code.

Comment: The [x operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Multiplicative-Operators) does not repeat code. It repeats a value or the contents of a string. Use a loop such as for/foreach to repeat code.

Comment: I suspect you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210). What is your actual goal? Why is removing the semicolon (as long as you're changing the source anyway) not the solution to that problem?

Comment: Check the edit for the problem

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you just want to print `"foo"` 5 times ?

If yes, then :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "foo" for (1..5);
```

Yields :

```
foofoofoofoofoo
```

Comment: `print "foo" x 5;` would also do that, and would do it more efficiently. The OP knows this, so the question isn't simply about printing `foo` 5 times.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I can't change print "foo"; I can add for( 1..5) after it but that leaves me in the same spot where I'd have to somehow escape the semi-colon in the middle: print "foo"; for(1..5);

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a source filter.
In fact it alters the code before executing it so you don't have to do it yourself.

```
echo package FiveTimes; use Filter::Simple sub{s/;/x5;/g};1; > FiveTimes.pm

perl -MFiveTimes -e"print qq/foo/;"
foofoofoofoofoo
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that kind of thing using a source filter -- but I can't imagine it being a good idea.

Comment: You are right. I could not imagine the question being a real world problem. Just wanted to show the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
 print "foo"; BEGIN{tie *STDOUT,'FiveTimer';sub FiveTimer::TIEHANDLE{bless{},'FiveTimer'}sub FiveTimer::PRINT{CORE::print STDERR $_[1] x 5}}
```

or more readably

```
 print "foo"; BEGIN{ tie *STDOUT,'FiveTimer' }
 sub FiveTimer::TIEHANDLE{bless{},'FiveTimer'}
 sub FiveTimer::PRINT{CORE::print STDERR $_[1] x 5}}
```

Comment: Can we avoid making up horrible code that solves a problem we don't understand yet? :)